# Image imported to drawable folder but does not show up when trying to set it to an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, drawable, src

I imported three images to my Android Studio (version 3.1.3) project by dragging them to the drawable folder (2 png, 1 jpg) and then File > Sync Project With Gradle Files.

In the xml file activity_main.xml (Text Mode), I type `android:src="@drawable/"` and I get my 2 png images as a suggestion but not the one I want to use (the jpg image).

Then I tried to set my src component using the activity_main.xml in Design Mode, selecting ImageView > src > ... . This opens a window with your Drawable content (Project, android, Theme attributes). Into Drawbale>Project I see the default android images and the two png images that I imported but the jpg is not there.

Then I delete all three images, Sync Project With Gradle Files, add the jpg file to the drawable file, Sync Project With Gradle Files and still did not show it when I tried to add it.

I saw that someone posted somewhere that he had a bug with the first image located in the drawable folder, and he import again the same image with a different name and it worked for him, tried but no success.

Comment: check once again you are putting image in drawable, some times android studio not suggest the names , so try to put image there and run !

Comment: Check if Android supports jpg as drawables, i remember having problems with that

Comment: @kdblue They were there, in Android Studio: Project Files Bar (Android > app > res > drawable) were all of them but the jpg did not show up when trying to add it to the ImageView

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I don't think it has problems specially with jpg files, I started another project and imported five png images, same problem. I posted an answer of how aparently worked with my other project, but it is not helping me now.

Comment: name of image must start with a letter, don't use numbers, then go to *Build* and click on *Rebuild project*

Answer (score 5):

- Make sure your image name does not have a capital letter, everything is lowercase.
- Your image name must have (a-z) or (0-9) or underscore only.

Answer (score 0):

I delete the jpg image, then duplicate it in another folder, imported both in the drawable folder, Sync Project With Gradle Files, Sync with File System, build the project without setting the image to the imageview, then somehow the original and the duplicate were there ready to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Open the folder "{your project}\app\src\main\res" with explorer, then make a copy of the same file (*.JPG or *.PNG) to the "drawable" AND "drawable-v24" folders, then rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the File menu of Android Studio and click on "Sync Project with Gradle Files" once you add your image files to the drawable folder.
After sync, when you type android:src="@drawable/", you get the images as a suggestion.